# Industrial recycling of mirrors

Tags: green-chemistry

I learned recently that mirror is mostly manufactured by pouring thin metal coating (i.e alumunium) on top of a substrate surface (i.e glass),

Due to the nature of this composition it cannot be easily disposed. I searched everywhere on how to recycle mirror and it always end up suggesting to recycle it physically (i.e artwork props etc.).

Assuming on industrial level mirror waste, how its getting recycled? I found no machine in market to do so.

My first thought will be separating the two in heat since both have different melting point, however not sure.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did not know the mirror can't be disposed on the glass recycling bins. I suspect that the whole story is economic in reason. The reflective coating is so thin that in some mirror can be even scratched by nails. Mirrors probably ruins the glass makers recipes (which already accommodate for a wide range of glasses, just think on the huge gamma of amber brown for beer or the dark for wine... I am really surprised and curious to see the real reason for the lack of mirror recycling companies / techniques, even more as I recall alumina and aluminosilicates are obviously in the feed.

Answer (score 4):

As @Alchimista states, the coating is nanometers, or at most a micron or two thick. It is *not* made by pouring aluminum, but by [evaporating it in a vacuum.](http://www.alcoat.net/alum_coa.htm) It is not difficult to remove such a thin coating by immersing the mirror for just a few seconds in $\ce{NaOH}$ solution; [this is part of the process of re-aluminizing](http://www.ing.iac.es/Astronomy/tonotes/alum/aluminizing.html) (is that re-aluminiumizing in GB?) telescope mirrors.

However, to protect the thin layer of metal on back-surface (daily use) mirrors, a layer of lacquer is applied, which might be more difficult to remove chemically.

That said, many recyclers reduce glass to [cullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_recycling) to be melted into generic glass items, such as glass-fiber insulation, or used to make other material, such as concrete and ceramics. Mirrors probably can be recycled as cullet.

Comment: For illustration about the described (first surface) telescope mirrors, which undergo intervals of getting this fine coating removed, and reapplied again a [small scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct3jtrMrrnQ), and [large scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkBgQaJVKjc) example. The (modern bright, second surface) mirrors,  lacquer-backed (e.g., in the bathroom) are double coated, first Sn to improve adhesion, then topped by the fine layer of silver reduced *in situ* ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u03S1Nmslw4)). The classic almagam mirror is darker and less frequently seen.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. But then how to strip off the coating completely in lacquer backed mirror? Leaving it out to pure glass which is much more convenient to handle/recycle @Buttonwood

Comment: @gardin If the glass is of [soda-lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda%E2%80%93lime_glass) type, then at the high melting temperature (vicinity of 1000 C), all organic material may combust. Perhaps the bit of Cu renders the glass unsuitable for the production of optical lenses (turquoise color, as reported [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_coloring_and_color_marking)), yet there are multiple other uses of recycled glass in addition to bottles and windows ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_recycling#Recycling_into_other_products)).

Comment: To summarize, mirrors (even for the case of lacquer double-backed mirror), could be recycled by putting them into certain solution for awhile to strip off the outermost coating, and then melting to flush the remaining? End result will be pure glass? Am i missing something? Again thanks a lot @Buttonwood